# JackRabbit on Wildfly 11

Tags: jackrabbit, jboss-wildfly-11

We are planned to use jackrabbit repository to store files.Trying to deploy jackrabbit on Wildlfy 11.

Downloaded jackrabbit-jca -2.8.7.rar from the following location
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jca/2.8.7/jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar

Got following exception when trying to deploy this rar file in wildlfy 11.
12:33:29,107 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool --72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."jackrabbit-jca -2.8.7.rar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar": WFLYJCA0046: Failed to start RA deployment [jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar]

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got deployed jackrabbit on Wildlfy based on these steps

**STEP BY STEP PROCEDURE ABOUT TO DEPLOY JACKRABBIT ON WILDLFY11**

```
1. Downloaded latest version of jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar file from following location

    http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jca/2.4.3/jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar

2. Configured Jackrabbit repo in standalone-full.xml under <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">

<resource-adapters>
    <resource-adapter id="jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar">
        <archive>jackrabbit-jca-2.8.7.rar</archive>
        <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jcr/local" enabled="true" pool-name="RabbitAdapter">
        <config-property name="homeDir">//The location you wish to store files</config-property>
        <security>
        <application/>
        </security>
        <validation>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        </validation>
        </connection-definition>
        </connection-definitions>
    </resource-adapter>
</resource-adapters>

3. updated the existing jca archive validation property as false under <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0">

    <archive-validation enabled="false"

4. Configured hsqldb as DefaultDS datasource in standalone-full.xml.

<datasource jndi-name="java:/DefaultDS" pool-name="DefaultDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:${jboss.server.data.dir}${/}hypersonic${/}localDB</connection-url>
<driver>hsqldb</driver>
<pool>
<min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
</pool>
<security>
<user-name>sa</user-name>
<password></password>
</security>
</datasource>

5. Created module in wildfly for hsqldb dependency

location : wildfly-11.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\hsqldb\main

jar : hsqldb.jar,hsqldb-plugin.jar

module.xml

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hsqldb">
<properties>
<property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>

<resources>
<resource-root path="hsqldb.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hsqldb-plugin.jar"/>
</resources>
</module>

Added hsqldb driver in standalone-full.xml under<drivers> tag

<driver name="hsqldb" module="org.hsqldb">
<driver-class>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver-class>
</driver>

6. Create a module for jcr dependency in Wildlfy 11
    location : wildfly-11.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\jcr\main

    jar name : jcr-2.0.jar

 module.xml

 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="javax.jcr">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jcr-2.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```