# Deploy Jackrabbit jca 2.21.15 on Wildfly 27

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jackrabbit, jca

I've been trying to deploy jackrabbit for a really long time.
I had used different versions of jackrabbit and wildfly a few years ago without success (I don't even remember the error).

I thought I'd try with the latest version but it seems to be even worse than before.

My resource-adapters config :

```
<resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15.rar">
                    <archive>jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15.rar</archive>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jcr/local" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15_rar-Pool" use-ccm="true">
                            <config-property name="homeDir">
                                /var/jcr/JCR/
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="configFile">
                                /var/jcr/JCR/repository.xml
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="bindSessionToTransaction">
                                true
                            </config-property>
                            <security>
                                <application/>
                            </security>
                            <validation>
                                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                            </validation>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
```

My error with or without resource-adapters definition :

{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.ra.deployer."jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15.rar"" => "WFLYJCA0046: Failed to start RA deployment [jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15.rar]
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15.rar
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/jackrabbit/jca/JCAResourceAdapter (Module "deployment.jackrabbit-jca-2.21.15.rar" from Service Module Loader): javax/resource/spi/ResourceAdapter"}}

I tried many things like :

https://users.jackrabbit.apache.narkive.com/1zhqxTvP/jackrabbit-jca-on-jboss [JackRabbit on Wildfly 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837982/jackrabbit-on-wildfly-11) https://sreekanthsnair.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/deploying-jackrabbit-to-jboss-as-7/

Thanks

I would like to first successfully deploy and then migrate the data from an old jackrabbit.

Answer (score 0):

Jackrabbit JCA resource adapter is not JakartaEE 10 compliant. You need to stay on WildFly 26 or upgrade the jackrabbit code to JakartaEE 10.

Comment: Thank you I will try this.
Where can I find this information? I haven't found it and would like to be kept informed when Jackrabbit is compatible.

Comment: I looked at jackrabbit resource adapter pom.xml

Comment: That was the problem. Now I'm having trouble with Derby but that's another issue. Thanks again.